# Login as a different user to a local network share in Windows 10 1903

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares, windows-10-v1903

How can I change the user name under which I am currently logged in to my local network share under Windows 10 Pro 1903? Either I am blind or I don't see a corresponding option for that.

Scenario:

1. I am accessing some local network share (namely `\\192.168.1.1\`), my home NAS.
2. Windows asks me for a login and password, which I provide and which are correct / accepted.
3. Six out of seven folders / network shares are accessible to all users assigned to this NAS, so I can browse them without any problems. I am accessing 7th share, accessible only by admins.
4. Windows asks me to provide network credentials again, but shows a different dialog window:

[image]

How can I change a user name in that dialog (namely to `admin`)? **User name field is not editable and the *More choices* button is disabled**.

I don't know if that matters here, but whenever I click anywhere within that dialog with my mouse, it gets frozen for about 10-30 seconds.

**Side note**: *I have started using Windows 10 Pro for past five hours, so this is something new to me.*

*For years I've been using Windows 7 Home with the very same home network / NAS and I had absolutely no problems. Whenever access was denied and new credentials were expected, I was always presented with a dialog where both user name and password were editable*.

Comment: Is this in a domain environment or just a home network? It's odd that 'More choices' is greyed out. Usually you could click that and choose to use a different username :-/ If you bring up a command prompt and type in '*net use*' are there any existing connections to that IP address?

Comment: @Smock I'm pretty sure this is something Microsoft did in an update in 1903.

Comment: Thanks everyone for a valuable content here, but unfortunately I must VTC this question as it is based on misunderstanding and thus brings no value to the community. The problem is mentioned in third to end sentence. The "More choices" button turned out to be not disabled, but it was the issue of whole window becoming "hanged" (not reacting, not movable) for around 10-30 seconds after clicking anywhere within it, except for password field. After waiting those 30 seconds until window become "unhanged", it was possible to click "More choices" button and provide different user name. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not reproducible and question is based on misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source of the problem is that Windows keeps one credential for each target.
So if you did one login to a remote computer, Windows kept the credential,
so the next time you login Windows only asks for the password because
it thinks it already knows the user name.

You need to make Windows forget the previous credential in order for it
to ask for the entire login information. The procedure is described below.

Start Credential Manager, click Windows Credentials,
then delete all credentials for the target computer.
If you also find `192.168.1.1` under Web Credentials, delete it as well.

The next time, Windows should prompt you for the user-name. If it still uses the old credential restart the computer and try again, it should work.

Comment: I would add that windows does not allow logging into a network resource with more than 1 user. If he connects to the old shares with his own username again and then tries to access that 7th share, it would fail again, and he would not understand why.

Comment: @LPChip You could probably trick this though - setting up an entry in the hosts file (eg `192.168.1.1 admin-share`), and using that to access it (\\admin-share\\). Assuming that this is the issue being experienced here.

Comment: @Smock sure. I know many ways to circumvent the issue, but that's not the point. If someone is not told this is an issue, they will not understand why this answer is correct. My point to Harry was just to add that little detail to the answer.

Comment: @LPChip: You are right, the answer is not complete without more background info. Thanks.

Comment: +1 I now fully approve the answer. :)